# Pandas groupby values with bin

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions, binning

It seems like a simple question, but I need ur help.

For example, I have df:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [2, 1, 3, 1, 8, 9, 6, 7, 4, 6]
```

How can I group 'x' in range from 1 to 5, and from 6 to 10 and calc mean 'y' value for this two bins?
I expect to get new df like:

```
x_grpd = [5, 10]
y_grpd = [3, 6.4]
```

Range of 'x' is given as an example. Ideally i want to be able to set any int value to get different bins quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
bins = [5, 10]
df2 = (df
 .groupby(pd.cut(df['x'], [0]+bins,
                 labels=bins,
                 right=True)) 
 ['y'].mean()
 .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
    x    y
0   5  3.0
1  10  6.4
```

Comment: One more qstn) How to transform new x (labels) to numeric format?

Comment: You can use `.astype({'x': int})`